# Grails save method returning null

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have been saving entities in my database in grails with the following shorthand...

```
def jim = new User(name: "Jim",
                emailAddress: "jim@hotmail.com",
                backOfficeUser: false,
                dateCreated: Instant.now(),
                lastUpdated: Instant.now(),
                passwordHash: BCrypt.hashpw("secret123", BCrypt.gensalt())).save(flush: true)
```

It all seemed to be working fine until something caused .save() and save(flush: true) are returning null.  If I change the statement to this it works fine however...

```
    def jim = new User(name: "Jim",
            emailAddress: "jim@hotmail.com",
            backOfficeUser: false,
            dateCreated: Instant.now(),
            lastUpdated: Instant.now(),
            passwordHash: BCrypt.hashpw("secret123", BCrypt.gensalt()))
            jim.save(flush:true)
```

The Jim instance would then immediately have an id issued by the database sequence and is persisted when save is called.

Comment: Try adding `failOnError: true` in `save` for the first case to see if there is any validation error.

Answer (score 6):

In grails save returns saved instance if save was successfull, if not - it'll return null. See [save reference](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/save.html) description section. Add `failOnError: true` to check if validation failed

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that another developer in the team had overridden the save method to retry when we hit a specific deadlock exception our database vendor can have under high load (Percona).

In this new save method we no longer returned the instance.